# How to find instance of a value type in Scala?

Tags: scala

I know `isInstanceOf` can be used to find value type, but how do I find the type of 'str'?

What type is it?

```
scala> val str = ("Scala", "Elixir","Spark")
str: (String, String, String) = (Scala, Elixir, Spark)
```

The following throws an error (exclude Any/AnyRef etc for now):

```
scala> str.isInstanceOf[List]
<console>:13: error: type List takes type parameters
       str.isInstanceOf[List]

scala> str.isInstanceOf[String]
<console>:13: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type (String, String, String) cannot also be a String (the underlying of String)
       str.isInstanceOf[String]
                       ^
res9: Boolean = false
```

I can check it this way but is there a name for this?

```
scala> str.isInstanceOf[(String, String, String)]
res12: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `:type` in scala repl to find type

Actual type is `Tuple3[String, String, String]`

```
str.isInstanceOf[Tuple3[String, String, String]]
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val str = ("Scala", "Elixir","Spark")
str: (String, String, String) = (Scala,Elixir,Spark)

scala> :type str
(String, String, String)

scala> str.isInstanceOf[Tuple3[String, String, String]]
res2: Boolean = true

scala> str.getClass
res3: Class[_ <: (String, String, String)] = class scala.Tuple3
```

Comment: Aha. Thanks. I guess the max size of 22 applies here?

Comment: How can I use `:type` programmatically rather than REPL?

Comment: @Bala Programmatically you can use `getClass` ... `scala> str.getClass
res3: Class[_ <: (String, String, String)] = class scala.Tuple3`

Comment: @Bala why would you need to determine a type programmatically? what's the use case?

Comment: @maasg I don't have a specific use case.  Just a question that popped up when learning.

Answer (score 2):

> How to determine val type programmatically?

For instance, you want to know the type of the value is some specific type?

```
// assign x value
val x: Any = "this is string"

// custom function evaluate type
def f[T](v: T) = v match {
  case _: Int    => println("Int")
  case _: String => println("String")
  case _         => println("Unknown")
}

// determine val type
f(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

The modern (meaning Scala 2.10 or later), Scala way of programmatically getting the compile time type of something is using a [`TypeTag`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.1/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/TypeTags.html).

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> def getType[T: TypeTag](value: T) = typeOf[T]
getType: [T](value: T)(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])reflect.runtime.universe.Type

scala> val str = ("Scala", "Elixir","Spark")
str: (String, String, String) = (Scala,Elixir,Spark)

scala> println(getType(str))
(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

scala> getType(str) <:< typeOf[(String,String,String)]
res1: Boolean = true

scala> getType((1,2,3)) <:< typeOf[(String,String,String)]
res2: Boolean = false
```

`getClass` will give your the erased runtime class. `isInstanceOf[T]` will test whether the erased runtime class is the same as or a subclass of the erased runtime class of `T`.

And "erased" means that the following evaluates to `true`.

```
(1,2,3).isInstanceOf[(String,String,String)]
```

"runtime" and "compile time" mean that this is `true`:

```
val a: Any = (1,2,3)
a.isInstanceOf[(_,_,_)]
```

while this is `false`:

```
val a: Any = (1,2,3)
getType(a) <:< typeOf[(Int,Int,Int)]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to determine a type programmatically is using Manifest:

```
scala> def getType[T: Manifest](t: T): Manifest[T] = manifest[T]
getType: [T](t: T)(implicit evidence$1: Manifest[T])Manifest[T]

scala> val str = ("Scala", "Elixir","Spark")
str: (String, String, String) = (Scala,Elixir,Spark)

scala> getType(str)
res0: Manifest[(String, String, String)] = scala.Tuple3[java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String]
```

Comment: I think Manifests are sort of deprecated in favor of TypeTags and ClassTags.

Answer (score 2):

This method can help you get the type of any val/var at runtime, it's also works in compiled code.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def printType[T](x: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Unit = println(tag.tpe.toString)

printType(List[Int](1,2,3))  // output: List[Int]
printType(("xxx", 123, 0.1)) // output: (String, Int, Double)
printType(2)                 // output: Int
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! `Recognizer.recognize(1)` returns `class Int<>`, so I think you should only return `"<" + args.mkString(",") + ">"`  if `args` is not empty. You can [edit] your answer.

Comment: @norbjd Thank you, I find a batter way to do this